# Non-http url link from HYPERLINK('notes://example.com', 'View') is not opening

Tags: lightning, formula, url, hyperlink, spring19

We have a text formula field with following code:

```
HYPERLINK("notes://example.com", "View")
```

When using Lightning Experience, thin link is not redirecting to address.

In Classic Experience new tab is opened.
[image]

Is there some security block implemented in Lightning Experience? Is it possible to bypass it using some url hack?

When inspecting the html element, is has no link!
[image]

Custom URL field type is not feasible, since it automatically pre-pends "http" before url in the field.

Comment: Hi Martin, did you find something useful? It seems that SF implemented some logic to strip all unknown URI scheme. We have the exact same problem. It works in classic, but not in Lightning. Interestingly, it still works for some more widely used schemes, e.g. tel:, mailto:,... For me, it seems to be some undocumented SF fix.

Comment: I just ran into this issue today as well. Someone from SF needs to comment on this

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You will want to change the last parameter from "View" to something like "_blank", "_top" or "_self".

I have a hyperlink which works on LEX just fine (not using a non-http, but the link works). Look at this example:

```
HYPERLINK('#/sObject/' & Asset.Opportunity__c & '/view', Asset.Opportunity__r.Name , '_self')
```

This is for a formula field which displays a hyperlink to a related custom reference to an opportunity on the asset object.

> The target parameter is optional. If you do not specify a target, the link opens in a new browser window. Some common target parameters are:
>
> _blank Displays link in a new unnamed window.
>
> _self Displays link in the same frame or window as the element that refers to it. _parent Displays link in the immediate frameset parent of the current frame. This value is the same as _self if the current frame has no parent.
>
> _top Displays link in the full original window, canceling any other frames. This value is the same as _self if the current frame has no parent. For more information on basic HTML tags, consult an HTML reference on the Internet. The HYPERLINK function is available everywhere that you can define a formula except default values, field updates, s-controls, validation rules, approval processes, custom buttons and links, and workflow rules.
>
> https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_functions_a_h.htm&language=en_US#HYPERLINK

Comment: Hello,
"View" is label shown in UI and "_blank" is third parameter by default, so it does not have to be specified.

I know that it works with regular Salesforce or http links. My issue is with non http links, such as "notes://example.com"